# Creating a Named step in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to learn groovy for my pipeline set-up and I'm stuck on something realy basic, but I don't know where to start looking to solve my issue.

What I'm trying to do is basicly create a stage with multiple Named steps. Underneath I've posted a basic example of what I'm trying to do, what would be the 'go to way' to do this.(this just creates a folder with a zipped file inside it).

Sidenote: This code currently throws the error

> WorkflowScript: 23: Expecting "interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep" but got Mkdir

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Zipfile'){
            steps{
                step('Mkdir'){
                    sh 'mkdir LocalDir'
                }
                step('Touch File'){
                    sh '''cd LocalDir
                    touch File
                    cd  ..'''
                }
                step('Zip'){
                    sh '''cd LocalDir
                    zip File.zip File
                    cd  ..'''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that `step` could be named?

Comment: It came from an example excercise. "Create a stage with multiple steps, each step has to be named"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found what the question was expecting... I should have added named stages with steps in them

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Zipfile'){
            stages{
                stage('mkdir'){
                    steps{
                       sh 'mkdir LocalDir'
                    }
                }
                stage('Touch File'){
                    steps{
                         sh '''cd LocalDir
                         touch File
                         cd  ..'''
                    }
                }
                stage('Zip'){
                    steps{ 
                          sh '''cd LocalDir
                          zip File.zip File
                          cd  ..'''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to disappoint you. You can't name a `step`. The [official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#steps) doesn't mention such a thing.

From the official documentation:

> steps
>
> The steps section defines a series of one or more steps to be
> executed in a given stage directive.
>
> Required: Yes
>
> **Parameters: None**
>
> Allowed: Inside each stage block.